# How do you match part of a repeating group to a part from a previous repeat, in Regex?

Tags: regex, regex-group

Suppose I have a data storage or filing system and I accept a few formats (legacy reasons, not my own design)

So for example, I need to accept

```
abcd.efgh.1234.4567
abcd-efgh-1234-4567
abcd|efgh|1234|4567
```

but not

```
abcd.efgh-1234|4567
```

Basically I need to be consistent about the delimiters I use. I am trying to construct a regex that can check that but I am finding it really tricky. I have explored regex references and see how they would work for finding repeats like `abc-abc-abc`, but in my case I need it to allow the `abcd` part to be different and only **ensure I have the same delimeter**

Here's what I've got so far ([link to Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Gu4x9e/1));

```
(([a-z1-9]){4}([\.:|])){3}(([a-z1-9]){4})
```

I need to somehow give a backreference to that `([\.:|])` but I can't put it in there since it needs to repeat on itself.

Is there anyway to do this in Regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the delimiter when it first appears, and then back reference it later:

```
[a-z1-9]{4}([.:|])(?:[a-z1-9]{4}\1){2}[a-z1-9]{4}
```

See regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gu4x9e/3).

- `[a-z1-9]{4}` matches a length four word;
- `([.:|])` matches and captures the delimiter;
- `(?:[a-z1-9]{4}\1){2}` captures the second and third patterns, the delimiter is referred to as the delimiter captured above;
- `[a-z1-9]{4}` matches the last word;

Answer (score 1):

Your regex could be `\w+([.|-])\w+\1\d+\1\d+` See: [**example 1**](https://regex101.com/r/cta3aZ/1)

It uses backreferences \1 to the first encountered separator ("|", "." or "-")

Test:

```
$ cat repeat.txt
abcd.efgh.1234.4567
abcd-efgh-1234-4567
abcd|efgh|1234|4567
abcd.efgh-1234|4567
```

Result:

```
$ grep -P '\w+([.|-])\w+\1\d+\1\d+' repeat.txt
abcd.efgh.1234.4567
abcd-efgh-1234-4567
abcd|efgh|1234|4567
```

Or, more generic:

```
$ grep -P '\w+(\W)\w+(\1\w+)+' repeat.txt
abcd.efgh.1234.4567
abcd-efgh-1234-4567
abcd|efgh|1234|4567
```

See: [**example 2**](https://regex101.com/r/cta3aZ/2). The problem with the last one, though, can be that a repeating group only captures the last occurrence.

Comment: Thanks I suppose this works as well but I was looking/hoping for something more generic

Comment: No I meant like a way in regex to match part of an inner group. In the expressions you wrote (which are great in any case) it sort of repeats itself and wouldn't be so great if, say, my input involved more sets of characters, i.e. `abcd-efgh-ijkl-mnop-qrs`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Look at https://regex101.com/r/cta3aZ/3 which uses the last proposed regex. It doesn't care about the number of character sets you use in between separators. The problem though is, it matches, but it doesn't capture all occurrences.

Comment: That's fine, in my case I don't need it to capture occurences. I just need to check if I can get a full match (`^` and `$` should actually be added)
I guess to make this more what I was looking for it would something like `\w{4}(\W)\w+(\1\w{4}){5}`